# how do i merge different express routes from different files in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

i recently migrated to typescript and i have encountered problem merging different routes from different ts files.

this is how i used to do it in js 

`app.use("/users/auth", require("./routes/user/auth"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/user/index"));`

is there a similar solution in ts??

This is my Route Class in ts

```
export default class Routes {
  public routes(app: Application): void {

    app.route("/").get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "GET request successfulll!!!!"
      });
    });

    app
      .route("/contact")
      .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "GET request successfulll!!!!"
        });
      })
      .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "POST request successfulll!!!!"
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i normally dont use typescript, but it should be the same like normal javascript i think.

you can do the following:

you have structure like following as example:

- controllers
- helpers
- public
- routes
  --index.js
  --api
  --- index.js
  --- sunbscriber.js
- views

in app.js:

```
app.use('/', './routes/index');
```

in directory routes in index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(require('./api');
module.exports = router;
```

in directory routes/api in index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/subscriber', require('./subscriber'));
module.exports = router;
```

in directory routes/api/ in subscriber.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  //Your Route
});
```

I dont know if this is best practise, but i like this structure, because you can defferenciate the diffrent routes. Its easy to configure additional middlewares for routes like login or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

do the following refactoring:

- rename the export command to:

  `export class Routes { ... }`
- make the `routes` method a static one:

  `public static routes(app: Application): void { ... }`
- import the class using the Typescript way:

  `import {Routes} from '/[path-to-file]'`
- change the `app.use` command to:

  `app.use('/...', Router.routes(app)); '`

Also, as another user has mentioned, express best practices suggest using a router instead of adding routes to the app instance directly:

```
export default class Routes {
  public routes(): Router {

    const router = express.Router();
    router.route("/").get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "GET request successfulll!!!!"
      });
    });

    router
      .route("/contact")
      .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "GET request successfulll!!!!"
        });
      })
      .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "POST request successfulll!!!!"
        });
      });

    return router;

  }
}
```

If you choose to go with this then you won't need to pass the app as parameter to the routes() call:
`app.use('/...', Router.routes());`

Comment: Router.routes(this.app) throws an errors saying type void can not be assigned to Application Type

Comment: I have modified the answer. I am writing this from mobile so it's possible that there is a bug/typo or two in there